# How was the Stabilo crewed re-entry vehicle supposed to work? A tractor engine with four nozzles?

Tags: engine-design, design, launch-escape-system, monopropellant

ARCA Space's webpage for the [Stabilo program](http://www.arcaspace.com/en/program_stabilo.htm) has a description and an image. Hydrogen peroxide monopropellant? Reaction closer to the crew than the nozzle?

With thrust at the top, it seems that <s>simplification due to inherent stability is a big advantage</s> no, per @RussellBorogove's [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20937/#comment56848_20937) that's not right. While the word "Stabilo" appears frequently, the "aerodynamic stability system at the top" does not refer to any passive stabilization due to thrust-at-the-top at all. It's something different entirely.

Why was the thrust put at the top, and how was the attitude controlled during the phase of descent that used this engine?

Also, wasn't it tempting to use all that free oxygen to get a boost from combustion? Or was that going in the wrong direction - adding complexity where simplicity was sought?

The problem with steam is that it condenses, shrinking by a factor of roughly 1000 in volume. Was it difficult to ensure that the steam was always above its local boiling point (noncondensing) at each location and pressure, at least until well outside of the nozzle?

[image]

Comment: Thrust at the top doesn't give any stability advantage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_rocket_fallacy  http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/why-are-rocket-engines-at-the-base-of-the-rocket

Comment: I don't think it did work.  They appear to have dropped this approach in favor of other speculative designs.

Comment: @OrganicMarble do you mean the system failed in some way, or that the project ended without going anywhere further?

Comment: From what I can tell none of the tests even lit the engine.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yikes - isn't the engine just steam from Peroxide decomposition? So much for simplicity!

Comment: The propellant tanks store peroxide, not steam. The decomposition occurs in the combustion chamber, and the exhaust won’t condense until it’s well out of the nozzle.

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to phrase the question "how was X supposed to work?" rather then "how did X work?" given that it seems to have never actually launched.

Comment: Stabilo *did* refer to passive stability due to use of tractor engines (with the claim that towing a mass on a cable magically made it work). They even named it the "Popescu-Diaconu stabilization method", and hyped it up quite a bit early on. They're better at getting investors to give them money than they are at building rockets.

Comment: I think you mean ".... than they are at *launching* rockets" @ChristopherJamesHuff they've built quite a few.... But I'm sure their latest water boiling aerospike rocket will launch real soon now

Comment: Building a lot of them hasn't made them good at building them. They can't even run their steam rocket above 1.85 bar (no, I didn't put the decimal in the wrong place) on the test stand because its tank leaks, and what comes out is a weak spray of steam and liquid water that barely makes the vehicle bounce in its suspending cables. They launch infrequently because their designs and fabrication are both incompetent.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff is there video? :-)

Comment: @uhoh here: https://youtu.be/IUE2v9mNgIQ?t=161

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I was totally disoriented for a moment! Where I live the internet ads are often game-related, so I thought that this was the leaky test stand https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBK87.jpg then the real video started and I *still felt* like I was looking at an animation. After a while the greater reality of what is (and isn't) being shown sunk in. *Thanks!*

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff speaking of big launch batteries [Are LiPo batteries more suitable for 1st stage electric power than Li-ion batteries?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35958/12102) is currently unanswered.

Comment: I still say they're good at building rockets, but I recognise the ambiguity in that people might think I was saying the build good rockets... and the sarcasm about their boiler rocket didn't come through at all.